# How do you save to WebArchive webView editable content?

Tags: cocoa, resources, webview, webarchive

I am trying to create a WebArchive from a WebView.  I have it working, but I have found a problem when I try and work with edited content.  This is what I am currently doing:

```
[webView setEditable:YES];
WebDataSource *dataSource = [[webView mainFrame] dataSource];

WebArchive *archive = [[WebArchive alloc]
        initWithMainResource:[dataSource mainResource]
        subresources:nil
        subframeArchives:nil];

[[archive data] writeToFile:destinationPath atomically:YES];
[[webView mainFrame]
 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest
     requestWithURL:
     [NSURL fileURLWithPath:destinationPath]
     ]];
```

Any edits I make to the content in the WebView do not get stored in the WebArchive.  Do I need to commit my changes back to the original file in order for this to work?  I would like it to save based on the content that is in the WebView.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That's what I'm doing and works OK here (i.e. writeToFile:atomically:). I guess there is something wrong with loading webarchive's content back to webview. Can you check if the file you've written in destinationPath is what you want, i.e. the edited one?

Comment: I am actually loading an HTML file (input.html) into the WebView and then trying to save that into a WebArchive (output.webarchive).  The saving works, but it seems to create the WebArchive from the original file and ignores the changes made.  When I say changes I mean that after setting [webView setEditable:YES] and then I delete or add text, then I save the WebArchive, none of my changes make it into the output.  Is that what you say you have working?

Comment: [dataSource mainResource] returns "A web resource representing the data source. The contents returned are based on the original downloaded data. You can use the returned value to create a WebArchive object instead of using the webArchive method." according to Apple Reference Library (hhttp://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebDataSource_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  At this point I believe I need a way to grab the source DOM from the WebView, then create a WebDataSource, then a WebArchive.  Any thoughts on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging for awhile, I was able to figure out the answer to my own question.  Here is how I did it:

```
WebResource *dataSource = [[[[webView mainFrame] DOMDocument] webArchive] mainResource];

WebArchive *archive = [[WebArchive alloc]
       initWithMainResource:dataSource
       subresources:nil
       subframeArchives:nil];

[[archive data] writeToFile:@"output.webarchive" atomically:YES];
```

Hope that helps someone.